# How to update UI after async Task in viewmodel

Tags: c#, async-await, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

In my `Xamarin.Forms` pcl project, I have a `xaml` page with `label`. I want to update `label` after some `async task`. In my ViewModel `constructor` I set default text for my `label`. And create a `async Task` function named `SomeTask()`.

**Question 1:** Where can I call `SomeTask()` function. Not able to call `async Task` function in `constructor`.

**Question 2:** How to update `Label` text after `async Task SomeTask()` function.

My code:

```
  public class MyPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {  
        private String _selectedText;
        public String SelectedText
        {
            get { return _selectedText; }
            set {
                if (_selectedText != value)
                {
                    _selectedText = value;          
                }       
            }
        }

        public MyPageViewModel ()
        {
            _selectedText = "Welcome";   //Default text
        }

        private async Task<string> SomeTask()
        {            
            return await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000); //Dummy task. It will return the status of Task.
                return "Thanks";         //Update Text       
            });         
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can call it from the constructor - although you cannot *await* it (small difference there.). Instead of returning the task, couldn't you do `string ret = await Task...; /*update text*/ return ret;`?

Comment: You can create an async Factory Method and make you constructor private. Then you call that method to create an instance of `MyPageViewModel` Inside that method, you can call `string str = await SomeTask`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use [my `NotifyTask` type](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.Mvvm.Async); it's described in my [MSDN article on asynchronous MVVM data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx), and I think it's the easiest approach:

```
public class MyPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private NotifyTask<string> _selectedText;
  public NotifyTask<string> SelectedText => _selectedText;

  public MyPageViewModel()
  {
    _selectedText = NotifyTask.Create(SomeTask(), "Welcome");
  }

  private async Task<string> SomeTask()
  {            
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Thanks";
  }
}
```

Your data binding would then be changed to bind to `SelectedText.Result` to display "Welcome" followed by "Thanks". There are other `NotifyTask<T>` properties for data binding, such as `IsNotCompleted`, `IsCompleted`, and `ErrorMessage`, which allows you to handle fault conditions via data binding as well.

If you don't want to use this type, you can do something similar on your own:

```
public class MyPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private string _selectedText;
  public string SelectedText
  {
    get { return _selectedText; }
    set
    {
      if (_selectedText != value)
      {
        _selectedText = value;
        RaisePropertyNotifyChanged(); // However you're doing this.
      }
    }
  }

  public MyPageViewModel()
  {
    _selectedText = "Welcome";
    var _ = RunSomeTask();
  }

  private async Task RunSomeTask()
  {
    try
    {
      SelectedText = await SomeTask();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // TODO: Handle the exception.
      // It *must* be handled here, or else it will be silently ignored!
    }
  }

  private async Task<string> SomeTask()
  {            
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Thanks";
  }
}
```

The constructor starts a `RunSomeTask` operation and then explicitly ignores its results (note that this means all exceptions will be ignored). The `RunSomeTask` is responsible for running `SomeTask` and handling its results (and exceptions). The result is just used to update `SelectedText`, and exceptions will be handled however you deem appropriate for your app.

Comment: Is NotifyTask supposed to be in Nito.MVVM? I'm unable to locate it

Comment: @Chucky: It's in Nito.Mvvm.Async.

Comment: Hey @Stephen Cleary - I can find it on the internet, but I get "No packages found" on Visual Studio when searching for it.

Comment: Make sure you allow prerelease packages.

Comment: Well I'll be danged. Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public MyPageViewModel()
{
    _selectedText = "Welcome";   //Default text
    SomeTask().ContinueWith(previousTask => SelectedText = previousTask.Result);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that block the UI ? or at least produce unexpected results as the task is not awaited and the caller might start using this instance before the task is done.

Comment: It shouldnt block the UI because we just creating task and start it. If we need to disallow caller to use SelectedText  before async call will finish, we need additional logic here, but it wasnt require for current question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an async Factory Method and make you constructor private. Then you call that method to create an instance of `MyPageViewModel`. Inside that method, you can call `string str = await SomeTask`

```
public class MyPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{  
     public async MyPageViewModel CreateAsync()
     {
         var model = new MyPageViewModel();

         SelectedText = await SomeTask();

         return model;
     }        

     private MyPageViewModel ()
     {
         _selectedText = "Welcome";   //Default text
     }

     private Task<string> SomeTask()
     {            
         return Task.Run(async () =>
         {
             await Task.Delay(3000); //Dummy task. It will return the status of Task.
             return "Thanks";         //Update Text       
         });         
      }
}
```

So instead of creating your model like this:

```
var model = new MyPageViewModel();
```

You create it like this:

```
var model = await MyPageViewModel.CreateAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**

Use delegate and event.

1. Create Delegate & associated event:

   - `private delegate void MyDelegate();`
   - `private event MyDelegate myEvent;`
2. Subscribe to the event in constructor:

   - `myEvent += async () => await SomeTask();`
3. Execute the event, where ever you need:

   - `myEvent(); //Note: Check the event for null, before executing`

**Problem 2:**

If on a non-UI thread, then:

- Use some framework class for executing UI operation: for example - Xamarin provides Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread
- We may always use DataBinding with the Label and only update the value of Binding Path from ViewModel, using event subscription.

---

```
string _message;

public string Message

        {
            get => _message;
            set
            {
                _message = value;
            }
        }
myEvent += () => Message = "New Value";

<Label Text = "{Binding Message}"/>
```